# Complicated regular expression. How to perform on multiple stages

Tags: php, regex

Here is the content from which I am going to filter:

```
YO_{
    YO_{
        YO_{
            McDonalds.
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to filter out the text between *YO_*{ and }. I did this:

```
$another_var = preg_replace_callback(
    '/YO\_\{(.*?)\}/s',
    function($matches) {
        return $matches[1];
    },
    $variable_where_the_content_is_stored
);
```

But it is returning:

```
YO_{
    YO_{
        McDonalds.
    }
}
```

instead of returning **McDonalds**

How do I allow the filter process (regex) to go through multiple stages?

The code is just an example, and uses only the concept of what I'm trying to build. The actual code is way more complex and may create confusion. I just need the idea of going through multiple stages of filtration.

Thanks! :)

Comment: To me, this looks like an actual parse-able data format, like JSON. You might want to consider actually looking into _other_ solutions than to use regex

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code: check the comments inside for the fixes.

```
print preg_replace_callback(
    '/.*YO\_\{\s*([^}]*?)\s*\}.*/s',  // mistake 1 check \s*([^}]*?)\s* and .*
    function($matches) {
        return $matches[1];  // mistake 2
    },
    $variable_where_the_content_is_stored
);
```

However, you can also do this using `preg_match()`

```
preg_match('/.*YO\_\{\s*([^}]*?)\s*\}/s', $variable_where_the_content_is_stored, $m);
print $m[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at recursive regular expressions. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html. Recent versions of php does support recursive regexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually alter your regex a little to this and use match:

```
YO_\{[^{}]+\}
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/pJ7jN8)

`[^{}]+` will match non `{}` characters.

If you want the inner text without spaces, you can use:

```
YO_\{\s*([^{}]+?)\s*\}
```

And extract the first element of the array containing the matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [recursive regex pattern](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php) with negative lookahead:

```
$str = <<< EOF
YO_{
    YO_{
        YO_{
            McDonalds.
        }
    }
}
EOF;
if (preg_match('/ YO_ (?!.*?YO_) \{ ( (?: [^{}]* | (?0) )* ) \} /sx', $str, $arr))
   echo(trim($arr[1])); // McDonalds.
```

Comment: Recursion is nice, but I wonder how is this is better than something like [`YO_{\s*(.*?)\s*}`](http://regex101.com/r/lI8wI4)?

Comment: @AmalMurali: No i didn't claim it is better. There are problems in `YO_{\s*(.*?)\s*}` that it doesn't necessarily enforce matching brackets.